# Drawing curved arrows to/from specific location

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw the curved arrows from the image below. I tried it using TikZ but I couldn't figure out how to draw the curved lines.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code you've been working on? So we have something to use without writing it from scratch. :)

Comment: I don't have anything that looks like it yet :/, but here are the lines:
`[CP [C \textbf{é} [C’[TP [ T {que} [T’ [vP {XP} [v [v’[VP V XP]]]]]]] \\ [CP \textbf{XP} [C {é} [C’[TP [ T {que} [T’ [vP \textbf{\sout{XP}} [v [v’[VP V XP]]]]]]]`

Comment: [Something like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w8GSi.png)

Comment: yes, just like that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `\tikzmark` that in our case takes two arguments:

```
\tikzmark{<reference name>}{<actual text>}
```

Later, we can draw regular arrows inside a `\tikzpicture` with some options to draw on top of the document.

### Output

[image: output]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta}
\newcommand\tikzmark[2]{
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)] \node (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}\noindent
[CP [C \textbf{é} [C’[TP [ T {que} [T’ [vP {XP} [v [v’[VP V XP]]]]]]] 
\newline
\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent
[CP \tikzmark{a}{\textbf{XP}} [\tikzmark{c}{C} é [C’[TP [ T {que} [T’ [vP \tikzmark{b}{\textbf{\st{XP}}} [v [v’[VP V XP]]]]]]]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\path (c.south) edge[thick, bend right,-{Latex}] (b);
\path (b.north) edge[thick, bend right,-{Latex}] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot, that really helps :)